# Load only up to a number of lines when loading a csv file in numpy

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

When working with large datasets, I often want to test my code with very few samples. This allows me to spot bugs before investing a long time in calculations.

One of the time consuming steps is often reading the data, so it's nice that Pandas lets me specify [nrows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) to read the file up to a certain line, then stop. I don't care about accuracy, but about code bugs.

I don't seem to find a similar functionlity when using numpy directly, either with [getfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) or [loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt). Am I overseeing something? I'll go ahead and look into it myself if it's not available, but I thought I'd check with you guys first. Thanks!

Comment: You could just still use `nrows` using pandas and then access the underlying numpy array by calling [`.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values) attribute of the dataframe

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13663832/3923281) solve the issue for you?

Comment: @EdChum Thanks. That'd work but Pandas will still try to figure out column types and the like when loading. True, if using only a few rows it won't make a difference. Hm. That'd work. Thanks!

Comment: @ajcr Yes it does, `itertools.islice` handles this nicely, if not pretty-ly. Also, this question is a duplicate. I didn't find the one you quoted, thanks!

Comment: @ajcr will you be posting this as answer? If you don't I will do it myself so as to declare the question closed. And thanks!

Comment: @Miquel: No problem! I hadn't written anything further, so happy for you to post the answer that you feel fits your question best.