# load a certain number of rows from csv with numpy

Tags: python, csv, numpy, genfromtxt

I have a very long file and I only need parts, a slice, of it.
There is new data coming in so the file will potentially get longer.

To load the data from the CSV I use `numpy.genfromtxt`

```
    np.genfromtxt(filename, usecols={col}, delimiter=",", skip_header=skip_head)
```

This cuts off a certain parts of the file in the beginning which already substantially speeds up the process of loading the data.
But I can't use `skip_footer` in the end to cut off the part after my slice that I want to use.

What I want is to only load a certain number of rows. e.g. lets say I skip the first 100 rows, then load the next 50 rows and skip the rest afterwards.

edit: I am using Python 3.4
edit: sample file: http://www.file-upload.net/download-10819938/sample.txt.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the slice using itertools, taking the column using itemgetter:

```
import  numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter
import csv
with open(filename) as f:
   from itertools import islice,imap
   r = csv.reader(f)
   np.genfromtxt(imap(itemgetter(1),islice(r,  start, end+1)))
```

For python3, you can use `fromiter` with the code above you need to specify the dtype:

```
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter
import csv
with open("sample.txt") as f:
   from itertools import islice
   r = csv.reader(f)
   print(np.fromiter(map(itemgetter(0), islice(r,  start, end+1)), dtype=float))
```

As in the other answer you can also pass the islice object directly to genfromtxt but for python3 you will need to open the file in binary mode:

```
with open("sample.txt", "rb") as f:
    from itertools import islice
    print(np.genfromtxt(islice(f, start, end+1), delimiter=",", usecols=cols))
```

Interestingly, for multiple columns using itertools.chain and reshaping is over twice as efficient if all your dtypes are the same:

```
from itertools import islice,chain
with open("sample.txt") as f:
   r = csv.reader(f)
   arr =np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(map(itemgetter(0, 4, 10), 
                                            islice(r,  4, 10))), dtype=float).reshape(6, -1)
```

On you sample file:

```
In [27]: %%timeit
with open("sample.txt", "rb") as f:
    (np.genfromtxt(islice(f, 4, 10), delimiter=",", usecols=(0, 4, 10),dtype=float))
   ....: 

10000 loops, best of 3: 179 µs per loop

In [28]: %%timeit
with open("sample.txt") as f:
   r = csv.reader(f)                                                               (np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(map(itemgetter(0, 4, 10), islice(r,  4, 10))), dtype=float).reshape(6, -1))

10000 loops, best of 3: 86 µs per loop
```

Comment: hm i can't import imap. I think it's because i'm using python 3.4

Comment: Just use map with python 3

Comment: do you mean to just replace imap with map?

Comment: had a mistake in the original code anyway, need to use the csv module to split the data. Can you add a sample of your file so I can run it locally?

Comment: now i get the TypeError: 'Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly'

Comment: @BlueScr33n,  for fromiter you won't,you can pass the islice object directly but you need to open the file in binary mode

Comment: ok I hope this is the last problem I am encountering. It tells me that the required argument 'dtype' (pos 2) is not found. Since when is dtype required? Also I still get this error even when I specify dtype after np.fromiter

Comment: You should not need to specify the dtype with genfromtxt, it is optional. If you don't provide it numpy will guess the datatype. What version of numpy as you using?

Comment: all right opening it in binary mode seems to be working

Comment: alright seems like I missunderstood something. I thought the end would be the number of columns that are loaded after the skipped rows. Now I get it :) 
I installed python with Anaconda and my numpyversion is 1.9.2

Comment: Nope,  end is where you want to stop, you just need +1 as it is half open.  It is all working?

Answer (score 2):

Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663721/limit-how-much-data-is-read-with-numpy-genfromtxt-for-matplotlib), you should be able to use `itertools.islice`, without needing `imap`, `map` or `csv.reader`:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

with open('sample.txt') as f:
    # this will skip 100 lines, then read the next 50
    d=np.genfromtxt(itertools.islice(f,100,150),delimiter=',',usecols={cols})
```

Comment: I tried, I get the TypeError: 'Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly'

Answer (score 2):

Starting `Numpy 1.10`, [`np.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html?highlight=genfromtxt#numpy-genfromtxt) takes an optional parameter `max_rows` which limits the number of lines to read.

Combined with the other optional parameter `skip_header`, you can select a slice of your file (for instance lines 100 to 150):

```
import numpy as np

np.loadtxt('file.txt', skip_header=100, max_rows=50)
```